# Qt - "Dynamically" promote a Widget

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtableview

**Situation :**

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume I have a StackWidget with different tabs, each of which has a widget to manage similar (but not the same) data types.

As the view to display the data and the controls to handle them are mostly the same, I created a new component (ui + cpp + h) named RemoteItemUi that contains the controls and the views and I use this component in each widget, to avoid duplication. It works.

**Problem :**

Each use case handles different data that each should use a custom TableView class deriving from QTableView. When I use RemoteItemUi, it comes with a QTableView.

**I need each instance of RemoteItemUi to use a specialization of QTableView.**

NOTES :

- I know that it is possible to promote widgets to a specialized type, the problem is that if I do this from Qt Designer in RemoteItemUi.ui, it will have the same specialization for all cases.
- I thought about replacing the QTableView instance dynamically after creation by a custom one, but as Qt doesn't have a clone() method or a copy constructor, I can't do it and retain properties of the original TableView defined in Qt Designer

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a nice use case for a graphical UI designer. You need to do this with code.

Comment: Perhaps abstract the data-handling into a separate component, so you can have one custom table-view class that handles all the different kinds of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up finding a satisfying solution. The component hasa function to be called by code to replace the TableView.

Here is the function :

```
void RemoteItemUi::initView(QTableView *newView)
{
    newView->setParent(this);
    newView->setStyleSheet(ui->tableView->styleSheet());
    setTableViewProperties(newView);

    auto oldLayoutItem = ui->verticalLayout->replaceWidget(ui->tableView, newView);
    delete oldLayoutItem;
    delete ui->tableView;
    ui->tableView = newView;
}
```

It has the following desired properties :

- Provides a way to set a customized TableView type
- Keeps the component easily usable in Qt Designer
- Stylesheets set from Qt Designer are retained in customized TableView

setTableViewProperties() sets some hardcoded properties to the customized TableView. They can be seen as a hand-made partial copy of properties.